# Paging objects within an object

Tags: javascript

I have a long list of chat rooms

```
let chatRooms = {
   "general": ChatRoom,
   "myRoomA": ChatRoom,
   "bobsRoom": ChatRoom,
   ...
}
```

`ChatRoom` has a `serialize` method

```
ChatRoom.serialize = function(){
    return {
      name: this.name,
      clients: this.clients,
      ...
   }
}
```

In order to list all ChatRooms to a user, I must send this data to them

```
ChatRoomManager.serialize = function(){
        let serializedObjects = [];
        Util.each(this.chatRooms, function(i, e){
            if(e.serialize){
                serializedObjects.push(e.serialize());
            }
        });
        return serializedObjects;
}
```

This becomes a performance issue as people regularly request to list all chat rooms and it gets serialized so often so I want to do paging. But if an object has no guaranteed order, how can I possibly say "here are the next 10 chat rooms"? Even if I could guarantee order, how could I start at index 11 without looping through all of the objects? Imagine if I was at index 1000, etc..

TLDR: is it possible to do paging with an object of objects efficiently and accurately.

Comment: Keep the room names in an array with whatever ordering you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coulf just take the values of the objects which returns an array, so the order is guaranteed:

```
  const ordered = Object.values(chatRooms);
```

You could now also apply a custom sort order, e.g.:

```
 ordered.sort((roomA, roomB) => roomA.name.localeCompare(roomB.name));
```

To now serialize only one chunk it is as easy as:

```
 let index = 0, chunk = 100;

 const result = ordered.slice(index * chunk, (index + 1) * chunk).map(room => room.serialize());
```